# Global JavaScript namespace and Mocha

Tags: javascript, tdd, mocha.js

I have been tasked with implementing Mocha tests for some JavaScript that already exists on a large website. This website has a global namespace object to hold all of it's functions and common vars, as well as a per page set within the same object, and I have attempted to use Mocha to recognise this but I cant seem to.

For example:

```
//global namespace declaration in the common.js file
var ns = {};
ns.commonValue = 1;
ns.commonFunc = function () {};

//extension of the namespace on an individual page
ns.thisPage = {};
ns.thisPage.pageVal = 1;
```

When testing the individual page JavaScript, ns is undefined.

Any help would be good.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your files are named

- common.js
- page.js

Then you should have

```
<script src="common.js"></script>
<script src="page.js"></script>
<script src="test.page.js"></script>
```

load page without mocha, and look at what inspector says, then correct, then add mocha